# Implementing a function that infers value type based on the key

Tags: typescript

I have an object type where keys map to different types:

```js
type Value = {
  str: string;
  num: number;
};
```

And I’m trying to implement a universal `format` function:

```js
const format = <K extends keyof Value>(key: K, value: Value[K]): string => {
  if (key === 'str') {
    // @ts-expect-error -- Property 'split' does not exist on type 'string | number'
    return value.split('').join('');
  }
  if (key === 'num') {
    // @ts-expect-error -- The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type
    return `${value - 1}`;
  }
  return '';
};
```

But why is TypeScript unable to narrow down `value`’s type inside an `if` condition?

I have an alternative working solution, but the function signature is quite inconvenient:

```js
type Value =
  | ['str', string]
  | ['num', number];

const format = (...[key, value]: Value): string => {
  if (key === 'str') {
    return value.split('').join('');
  }
  if (key === 'num') {
    return `${value - 1}`;
  }
  return '';
};
```

Interactive code on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/PTAEBEHsFMGcDsDkAXUB3SAnA1gLgFD7ICeADtKAGoCGANgK4UC8oA3vqKLMprlzwEt4AcwDcHUPHoBbPlOkAjaJnEBfcfgDGkeN1AAzLNOqoWAHgDSoaAA9k0eABNYobNGKR9VOowB8ACjdiPgsAGlAANx9oPhoGaABtCwBdAEo+bkwhYVAmXzYJAS9A91ymFkRMxFSCzk5MaGR6THhI6IA6WFJaAWR-RGr2gCtIIX7q8U5VQuKgsor5atq6hqaW0AADABJWKPjQAFpQAEZVDcnQafrG5taBtQ1DTGM+yp5EcJRbZAn8J5f+otwsdUhoQKAAOpYbCwAhEMgUOKMABMuQkAB9QAk3pgPvwsiJkhisYggZIZEpMMkwWBAGQEoAU9FQ+no8E0yAEOi4AmE8BMzQoAhcAEd6L1BWydBEHAIHMgCNpdMyjCZUSx-O1NQk+dJoOE9oxkrFosj0vjsrl8uxOEVQP4dcxyqAcUtrSsbusDdBOt1euNUsNRvB-RcrqBbfbqLr5s7FjU3dc1q1trtoocTmdQxJVrdnYgHoR-qr+lVPvY7L8i8hkYCZHiQaIgA).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I can confirm the the second approach is the the one that will solve this issue. The only improvement would be to create the `Value` tuple from the value interface, and name the tuple elements to make call site look better

Comment: This would be the improved version  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/PTAEBEHsFMGcDsDkAXUB3SAnA1gLgFD7ICeADtKAGoCGANgK4UC8oA3vqKLMprlzwEt4AcwDcHUPHoBbPlOkAjaJnEBfcfhCgA6lmywCRMhRoNoAFXqlazNqAkBtAAqghobNGKQAZlTqMAXVA+Bw9iPicAGlAAN39oPlNGZwCA-FVQzx8-MzTNMEAyAlAFelRvengAY2QBSHguAWF4amR6TAoBWFAAR3oBZA6qupjoeAFR5AJKuu5QbyxpFoAmUBYACgA6LYdm6WhouNzE+MtraABKPm5MIWFVgD42CQFfNd3mJhZEa8Rzp85OO1Wph6odGBtYNZ+mtEL8NgArSBCGG-cScVTPV7vVafUCIeS-f4AoFteoAAwAJKwwRQALSgACMqjJaNAGMB0GB9Vhag080wi2QSxhP2iKGgAA9kKj8PzBcL8TJENEGedREA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Yeah, I was just noticing how the OP changed `Value`... Any idea what question we can point to to cover this? It seems to come up often enough we should have a canonical target...

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - If not, though, this would make a great canonical if you know the "why" part. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why is TypeScript unable to narrow down `value`’s type inside an if condition?

Because it wouldn't be sound from a type perspective, but it's something a lot of us trip over, it's not just you. :-) It's not sound because we can supply an explicit type argument that would make `value`'s type ambiguous. One example (possibly *the* example?) of that is if we provide an explicit type argument with a union of the keys that allows us to give the wrong key for the value type we're providing:

```typescript
format<"str" | "num">("str", 42);
```

With the original definition of `format`, that call raises no errors, but at that callsite `K` is `"str" | "num"` (even though `key` is `"str"`) and so `Value[K]` is `string | number`, not `string`, and we can supply a number for it as above. So `key === "str"` doesn't, in that call, let us narrow the type of `value` to just `string`.

Unions are often the reason (or at least, often *a* reason) this sort of thing doesn't work when it seems like it should. :-)

You solve that by doing what you've shown in the question, which lets us control the type of both of them in tandem (and in this case, without a type parameter), but it can be simpler with a utility type like [the one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/PTAEBEHsFMGcDsDkAXUB3SAnA1gLgFD7ICeADtKAGoCGANgK4UC8oA3vqKLMprlzwEt4AcwDcHUPHoBbPlOkAjaJnEBfcfhCgA6lmywCRMhRoNoAFXqlazNqAkBtAAqghobNGKQAZlTqMAXVA+Bw9iPicAGlAAN39oPlNGZwCA-FVQzx8-MzTNMEAyAlAFelRvengAY2QBSHguAWF4amR6TAoBWFAAR3oBZA6qupjoeAFR5AJKuu5QbyxpFoAmUBYACgA6LYdm6WhouNzE+MtraABKPm5MIWFVgD42CQFfNd3mJhZEa8Rzp85OO1Wph6odGBtYNZ+mtEL8NgArSBCGG-cScVTPV7vVafUCIeS-f4AoFteoAAwAJKwwRQALSgACMqjJaNAGMB0GB9Vhag080wi2QSxhP2iKGgAA9kKj8PzBcL8TJENEGedREA) [provided by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74612652/implementing-a-function-that-infers-value-type-based-on-the-key?noredirect=1#comment131701486_74612652) [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir). Here's a genericized version:

```typescript
type KVTuple<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: [key: P, value: T[P]];
}[keyof T];
```

Now we can write `format` using your original `Value` interface by using that as the type argument to `KVTuple`:

```typescript
const format = (...[key, value]: KVTuple<Value>): string => {
    if (key === "str") {
        return value.split("").join("");
    }
    if (key === "num") {
        return `${value - 1}`;
    }
    return "";
};
```

The formerly-problematic call is no longer possible:

```typescript
format<"str" | "num">("str", 42);
//     ^−−−−− Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1. ts(2558)
```

...and so TypeScript knows that if `key` is `"str"`, `value` is `string` and otherwise (in this case) it's `number`. And it's not that hard to write (once you have `KVTuple`) and type hints for the parameters in the IDE still work nicely:

[image: TypeScript playground showing a call to format being written with the key set to "str" and a type hint showing the type of value is string]

Full example ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4&ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLxQN4Cgq6gZ2ACcAuA4gSwDsBzAbhzyqQFszmWAjCIhgXwZZQkKAGkYAFSRgEEADwSAfFHTY8UANoAFKNSgBrCCAD2AMygSAumQ2GQZLQBooAN0QoyE7Zcv9bRswtfLCFwaAANFTFJaVk5eGQIRUEAY2MqQihTYyIWOGAogAoAOlL-EGc3ROtoqRl5BJRFAEoyQiJqGhVlNTwKc0K7FVR0ACJ20ebMRnVcIghgJCIqV3cIYvwZCmBC0cnigCtjal3JhnU+Gd0BoZGxjknp2bx5xeWoAAMAEgwqlCgALRQACMfA+5zwl3UryWKz2-EE2Vy+V2E2co2AEAAHsAzs98VAAPSEqAAdRy+nwWCReR2owezmBzToBNZuGJZIpVJpKPGxFGjOZbNZHIAokQiDkoHB8FAACYQfAUeZy6k5Wm7BlQDHY3FC4XskniyVEaWyhVKlVq5HAOR8oijKAAH21D0UqP5zgALAAmfVEo0SqUy+WK5UQOVAA)):

```typescript
type Value = {
    str: string;
    num: number;
};

type KVTuple<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: [key: P, value: T[P]];
}[keyof T];

type X = KVTuple<Value>;

const format = (...[key, value]: KVTuple<Value>): string => {
    if (key === "str") {
        return value.split("").join("");
    }
    if (key === "num") {
        return `${value - 1}`;
    }
    return "";
};

format("str", "text");              // Works
format("num", 1);                   // Works
format("str", 1);                   // Error as desired
format("num", "text");              // Error as desired
format<"str" | "num">("str", 42);   // Error as desired
```